# C++ memory allocation (constructor)

Tags: c++

I need to write class which contains char pointer to text line and constructor which retrieves text line from the list of arguments, dynamically allocates memory and copies the text of the line to the component class.
Writed programm doesn't works correctly. Example [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8rF2.png).
What is wrong? Please help!

```
class A
{
    char* text;
public:
    A(char *line); 
};
A::A(char *line) {
    int length = strlen(line);
    text = new char[length];
    if (strlen(line) <= sizeof(text))
        strcpy_s(text, length, line);
    else
    {
        cout << text << endl;
        cout << "Too long string" << endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    A ob("aaaaaa");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to leave space for the null terminator. Also, there's no `strcpy_s` in C++.

Comment: `sizeof(text)` is not doing what you think it's doing.  Plus I don't see any reason to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator returns the size of the object (not the size of a string). So in this case

```
sizeof(text)
```

It returns the size of the object `text`. You declare `text` as

```
char* text;
```

So it returns the size of a `char*`. The exact size of this will depend on the system, but lets guess its `4`. So any string that has a length greater than `4` will result in the output of:

```
Too long string
```

If we look at the string: "aaaaaa" is longer than 4 so you get the expected output.

I expect you are trying to check that the previous line succeded.

```
text = new char[length];
```

But in C++ the `new` will either work or throw an exception (causing program termination for this program). So either that line works or the program will exit. So there is no need to check the result of `new` (unlike C where you should check the result of `malloc()`)

Also note: You should check the result of `strcpy_s()` as it will return an error on failure. Since you do not provide enough space in the destination it will indicate an error (you don't provide space for the null terminator).